# Case insensitive completion for git in zsh

Tags: git, zsh, zsh-completion

I have zsh setup to do case insensitive completion but somehow file matching for git completion remains case sensitive:

```
% zsh -f
% autoload -U compinit && compinit
% zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
% setopt nocasematch
% touch Foo
% ls fo[TAB]
% ls Foo # completes to foo
Foo
% git add fo[TAB] # does not complete
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: take `_git` from Zsh's 'master' branch. Latest version of Zsh today is 5.0.5, zsh's master I took `_git` from is at commit `c8e5be9d0fbbc6fb1cf06175b7c3d4757f6d973c`.

Repository is at `git://git.code.sf.net/p/zsh/code`.

With these unreleased changes completion for `git-add` is case insensitive.

At Zsh-5.0.5 stuff like `git-diff` is case insensitive but `git-add` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
% zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:files' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

I don't know why this is necessary, probably something in the implementation of the _git completion code.  That thing is over 6000 lines long.

Comment: Did this fix it for you? Does not work here. Neither with `zsh -f` nor with my complicated zshrc getting used.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with git diff instead of git add.  It turns out that the above has no real effect.  I tried digging into the completion code but got lost pretty quickly.